# error when launching rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this error when i try to execute "rails server" on debian8:

> /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in 'load': cannot load such file --
>   /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/railties-4.1.8/bin/rails
>   (LoadError)   from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in ''

Comment: what have you done

Answer (score 1):

```
$ gem list


$ gem install rails
```

Run the command again. It will download and install missing dependencies, including railties.